# What JQuery function is called when the page has loaded? What is the standard shorthand for this function?

Tags: jquery

What JQuery function is called when the page has loaded? What is the standard shorthand for this function?

Comment: My feeling is that OP has asked expecting some upvotes. Sorry, not clever.

Comment: @dheerosaur , he just joined, don't discourage him like that , he might not be really knowing it, whats wrong in asking

Comment: @user read this link http://api.jquery.com/ready/ for better understanding

Comment: @dheerosaur, I doubt it. "No username", 1 reputation, there is a chance that the OP doesn't even know what the heck are upvotes for.

Comment: @Tom , i agree with you , he just joined today//

Comment: @gov, These days, I have been commenting on a lot of questions like this. I really got tired of writing "Please search before asking". Btw, I didn't downvote.

Comment: Looking at the answers, the "standard shorthand" doesn't seem to be so standard. So while we're at it I'd like to ask: Why is almost nobody ever advocating the `jQuery(callback)`/`$(callback)` syntax?

Comment: @Tom, I guess you are right. Not so 'clever' from me.

Comment: @deceze, document.ready conveys some meaning and its useful for new people, function is little bit confusing as it looks like regular function name...

Comment: @gov Lowest common denominator programming? :o) I guess I just value terseness much more.

Answer (score 0):

Who'd have thunk? [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3)!

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // gets executed on page load
});
```

Answer (score 0):

None.

You are the one who's saying jQuery what to do.

The beginning of everything for jQuery mostly starts with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

But I said mostly, because there are lots of other ways to start executing jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
alert("loaded")
 });
```